# how to convert Json raw object or property cast in to specific model?

Tags: c#, json

```
        public class TransferJson
        {
            public object json { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
            public bool IsChanged { get; set; } = false;
            public string tempData { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        }

        public partial class Territory
        {                                 
            public string TerritoryID { get; set; }
            public string TerritoryDescription { get; set; }
            public int RegionID { get; set; }                                                
        }
```

> **i have 2 classes one is basically for transfer data and another is for serialize and deserialize data.  i am using object to send data over api
>   however it is not properly deserialize**

```
  Territory territory = new Territory();

    territory.TerritoryDescription = "Test";
    territory.TerritoryID = "Test";
    territory.RegionID = 1;


       TransferJson objTrf= new TransferJson();
        objTrf.json= territory;
        objTrf.Id = 1;
        objTrf.IsChanged = false;


    var SerializeData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objTrf);
    var DeserializeData= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransferJson>(SerializeData);

    var TerritoryData = DeserializeData.json as Territory; // i am getting null here 
    var Rawobject= DeserializeData.json as object; // i am also not proper getting data here
```

Comment: When asking a question related to code, it is always necessary to add a tag for the language you're using. Please [edit] your post to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json` type is `object`, and it deserialized as `dynamic` object, so you should to deserialize again `DeserializeData.json` to get the expected result, like :

```
Territory territoryData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Territory>(DeserializeData.json.ToString());
```

I hope you find this helpful.